# Lighting effects with 2D sprites

Tags: javascript, html5

I would like to know how to best achieve lighting effects with 2D.

I guess the only way is to make sprites of the area to be lit in specific colors?
Say I have a streetlamp, and around this place sprites to make it appear lit?

Is there a better way?

Edit: Found a good screenshot of what I'm looking for:
http://www.saltgames.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/multipleLights.png

Comment: What *kind* of lighting effects do you want? Post images of the effects you want so we can help you better.

Comment: Had some trouble finding good examples, but here's pretty much what I'm thinking: http://whilefun.com/img/games/screens/examples/2D_Lighting/screen01.jpg allthough I dont want the 'grid' to be so obvious, so round would be cool.

Comment: http://www.saltgames.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/multipleLights.png This image represents pretty much the style I'm going for.

Comment: This 2 steps video tut may help you on the way : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GI63eeaXbWs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BtjcH-iLR0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Canvas, you may use a radial gradient:

1. create a radial gradient from a light color on the center, to a transparent color on the end [see createRadialGradient](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-createradialgradient)
2. use `globalCompositeOperation="lighter"` is the trick to add color components and make the light effect
3. draw the created gradient on top of the image you want to light

---

This is basically one of the tip I used to implement [illuminated.js](http://greweb.me/illuminated.js/#%7B%22lights%22:[%7B%22instance%22:%22Lamp%22,%22position%22:%7B%22x%22:142.5,%22y%22:119.39999389648438%7D,%22distance%22:138,%22diffuse%22:0.8,%22color%22:%22rgba%28245,209,148,0.7063461328065751%29%22,%22radius%22:2,%22samples%22:6,%22angle%22:0,%22roughness%22:0%7D],%22objects%22:[%7B%22instance%22:%22DiscObject%22,%22center%22:%7B%22x%22:124.5,%22y%22:174.39999389648438%7D,%22radius%22:33%7D,%7B%22instance%22:%22PolygonObject%22,%22points%22:[%7B%22x%22:206.5,%22y%22:66.39999389648438%7D,%7B%22x%22:367.5,%22y%22:140.39999389648438%7D,%7B%22x%22:269.5,%22y%22:254.39999389648438%7D,%7B%22x%22:291.5,%22y%22:161.39999389648438%7D,%7B%22x%22:292.5,%22y%22:161.39999389648438%7D,%7B%22x%22:210.5,%22y%22:121.39999389648438%7D]%7D],%22globals%22:%7B%22maskcolor%22:%22rgba%280,0,0,0.81%29%22%7D%7D), in case you want to see some real usage and code.

Comment: It looks awesome, but when I'm moving objects around it is very choppy, is this due to your setInterval settings being rarely updated or performance issues? Will it run smoothly in a game with all the extra functions that comes with it?

Comment: An alternative is to use precomputed "light circle" images that you just blend onto the scene at the desired position.  Radial gradients, mostly transparent, with a white or pale yellow coloring work well.  Getting it to look nice might require experimenting with the gradients a bit, as a simple linear falloff will not look right.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Set the background to black.

Step 2: Calculate how much light is the tile getting (how far is it from light source(s), etc.).

Step 3: Lower the opacity of the image by a value according to what you calculated in Step 2.

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644399/brightening-an-image-using-styles-or-javascript

Comment: This would result in lighted tiles though right? Because I don't want the grid to be obvious.